# If $x>y\ge1$ are integers, with $x$ even and $y$ odd, and $x^4+4x^3y-4xy^3-4y^4$ is a square, must $y \mid x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

The title says it all: Let $x$ and $y$ be integers, with $x$ even and $y$ odd, such that $x > y \ge 1$ and
$$x^4+4x^3y-4xy^3-4y^4 = w^2$$
for some integer $w$. Does this force $y \mid x$?

Brute force calculations seem to support that conjecture. In fact, they suggest the stronger conjecture $x=2y$.

I’ve poked around trying to prove something, but can’t figure out the magic incantation. Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the curve $y^2=x^4+4x^3-4x-4$. We’re being asked to find (some of) its rational points (the conditions being signs and parity)… this has certainly been implemented in Sage or Magma.

Comment: @Aphelli: Well, yes… but I’m looking for an algebraic proof!  :)

Comment: I didn’t say anything about a proof… it might be a disproof for all we know? But what do you consider an algebraic proof? If the algorithm performs descent and finds a generating set for this “singular elliptic curve” which proves your remark true, does this count?

Comment: Also, here’s the “Elliptic Curve Handbook” for anyone who would want to do the computations by hand: https://webs.ucm.es/BUCM/mat/doc8354.pdf .

Comment: I’d need to double check, but it seems that $x=951017531851446281396498,
y=780923760568941116026369$ is a solution…

Comment: Confirmed! Write up an answer with the counterexample and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the pair $x=951017531851446281396498, y=780923760568941116026369$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The method is the same as the infamous https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/azf0zo/im_stuck_on_this_one/ . Solve instead when $x/y$ and $w/y^2$ are rationals. This gives a singular genus one curve: resolve it into an elliptic curve. Said elliptic curve turns out to have rank one, so try powers of the generator until one fits the bill…

Answer (score 3):

I also tried a brute force approach, and it seems that for $x=265$ and $y=222$, you do get a square $143736121=11989^2$, but $222 \not\mid 265$.

[Edit: in a previous version of the question, the conditions on the parity of $x$ and $y$ were not there.]

Comment: Yes, sorry… I added an extra condition in an edit: $x$ is even and $y$ is odd.